# tensorflow variable printing as NaN

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.constant(0, name='x')
n = tf.constant(0, name='n')
y = tf.Variable(x/n, name='y')

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    for i in range(5):
        x = x + np.random.randint(1000)
        n = n + 1 
        print(session.run(x))
        print(session.run(n))
        print(session.run(y))
```

I'm trying to print a rolling average for the random number generated by `np.random.randint(1000)`. Here's the output:

```
378
1
nan
1242
2
nan
2020
3
nan
2453
4
nan
2563
5
nan
```

As you can see, `print(session.run(x))` works as expected, as does `print(session(n))`. However, `print(session.run(y))` gives `nan`! Why?

Answer (score 2):

You get nan because you try to print 0/0.
First x and n should be variables because they change their values.
y shouldn't be because it's the result of an operation.

Your code should look like:

```
x = tf.Variable(0, name='x')
n = tf.Variable(0, name='n')
y = x/n

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    for i in range(5):
        ops = [
          tf.assign_add(x, np.random.randint(1000)),
          tf.assign_add(n, 1)]
        session.run(ops)
        print(session.run(x))
        print(session.run(n))
        print(session.run(y))
```

Comment: But if x and n are constants, how come I'm successfully changing their values in the loop?

Comment: You are not. the python variables x and n will point to the result of adding something to the original constant. If you add a line `x = n` you don't assign the value of the tensorflow variable, but instead have two python variables that refer to the same tensorflow constant.